# Moving from Magento Go to CE

Tags: magento-community, magento-go

I am moving a store from GO to CE.  I've exported the products to a csv.  My issue is that the original store has leading zeros on the skus but when I open up the csv in Excel it kills the leading zeros.  I need to edit the top row attributes but when I do the zero issue comes up.

Is there a way to fix that?  There are only 2000 skus but I'd rather not go cell by cell.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to edit this would be either do so in a text editor of choice, or convert the fields to strings in Excel.  The original CSV data is most likely good, it's just Excel's view of it.

Answer (score 0):

Excel allows to set column format during CSV import. Make sure that SKU is a string (or text or whatever it is in Excel), not number.